# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'compatMode' of undefined

Tags: java, selenium

When I am running automation script in google chrome browser and I am facing following issue.

Code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 

   "D:\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");  
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);

    driver.get(url);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("ImgLogo")).click();
    System.out.println("logo was clicked");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='TxtUserId']")).sendKeys("AUT11");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='TxtPwd']")).sendKeys("AUT11");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='btnSecureLogin']")).click();

    driver.quit();
}
```

Error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387) on 
port 25570
Only local connections are allowed.
Jan 04, 2019 3:44:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown 
error: Cannot read property 'compatMode' of undefined
 (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 
(ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 
x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Does your code compile ? It seems like line setting System property has wrong slashes. Try to replace with this:   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe");

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Desktop\\chromedriver_2.45.exe");  
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: What is a difference between this code and question code ?

Comment: Difference is capabilities in first line (WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap))

Comment: I tired that one also. Its working same problem